# file (mp3 music file) sending and receiving using socket

Tags: windows-phone-7, sockets, mp3

I am currently working on a WP7.5 project, and in this project i need to send an mp3 file from PC (desktop app) to the WP7.5 app.

I am using TCP socket for that, but using sockets i can only send and receive text message. Can anyone help me by giving sample code for sending and receiving file over socket (WP7.5 onwards).

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much send any amount of data via sockets. You are basically sending bytes which means you can either encode text or send byte representation of anything, like music files.

Check [this article](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/tcp-based-sockets-windows) for more details on how to use TCP in WP.